# Meteor page reload with Roles

Tags: meteor, roles

I am having a problem with Roles in my application when I reload the page. If I use the buttons and so on and navigate like you should on a website the problem is not there.

But what is the problem? In my meteor template, I should show a different view for admins and normal users, so in my template onRendered function I check the role and react on that. Here follows the code:

```
/* Predefined changes to current html are done in this function!*/
Template.Planning.onRendered(function () {
    var userid = Meteor.userId();
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(userid,'admin', Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP)){
        //do something
    }
});
```

For a specific reason the code inside the if-block is not executed when I am logged in as admin but reload the page. It does work when I visit it using the navigationbar, so I guess the Roles are not yet loaded when the onRendered-function is called. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `alanning:roles` works in a way, that it "autopublishes" the roles definitions to the client, so that you are able to have them available "immediately".

Immediately means in this case, when their subscription is ready. Until then the function `Roles.userIsInRole` will not return anything truthy.

In order to check of they are available use the reactive `Roles.subscription.ready()` method.

If you have trouble with reactivity in `onRendered` you may check for the roles in `autorun` of `onCreated`.

For example:

```js
Template.Planning.onCreated(function () {
  const instance = this
  instance.state = new ReactiveDict()
  instance.autorun(() => {

    if (Roles.subscription.ready()) {
      var userid = Meteor.userId()
      if (Roles.userIsInRole(userid,'admin', Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP)){
        instance.state.set('isAdmin', true) // reactive data source
      }
    }

  })
})
```

**Using it in a router**

You can even use this method on the router level in order to "wait" for all the roles to be loaded. This makes sense especially when your client routing logic makes heavy use of roles to manage access.

**Note on Security**

Don't forget, that this is just UI Candy. Roles (as well as routes) on the client can be bypassed. Re-check every method call and subscription that are sensitive twice in side the methods / publications using `Roles.userIsInRole`.

Comment: how do I use that instance.state in onRendered?

Comment: `const instance = this` and then `instance.state` but `onRendered` will not be triggered by a reactive data source update but only on rendering update, which is why `onCreated` and `autorun` will be better suited for that.

Comment: `if (Roles.subscription.ready()) {` surrounding the code that checks if user is in role is working . Thanks!